# JAVASCRIPT Data Type Issue

Tags: javascript, function, types, type-conversion

I am currently learning JS and when I do some practice, I find some issues I am unclear on data type in Javascript. I understand that JS do NOT require specific type indication, it will automatically do the type conversion whenever possible. However, I suffer one problem when I do NOT do type conversion which is as follows:

```
        var sum = 0;
        function totalSum (a) {
            if (a == 0) {
                return sum;
            }
            else {
                sum += a;
                return totalSum(--a);
            }
        }

        var i = prompt("Give me an integer");
        // var num = parseInt(i); 
        alert("Total sum from 1 to " + i + " = " + totalSum(i));
        // alert("Total sum from 1 to " + i + " = " + totalSum(num));
```

I notice that the code works perfectly if I change the data type from string to int using parseInt function, just as the comment in the code does. BUT when I do NOT do the type conversion, things are getting strange, and I get a final result of 054321, if I input the prompt value as 5. AND in a similar way, input of 3, gets 0321 and so on.

Why is it the case? Can someone explain to me why the totalSum will be such a number? Isn't javascript will automatically helps me to turn it into integer, in order for it to work in the function, totalSum?

The sample code can also be viewed in http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/66ghktd2/.

Thanks.

Comment: `i` is a string, need to convert it to a number, `Number(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to decompose what's happening in the `totalSum` method.

First the method `totalSum` is called with a string as parameter, like doing `totalSum("5");`

Then `sum += a;` (`sum = 0 + "5"` : `sum = "05"`) (note that `sum` become a string now)

then `return totalSum(--a);`, `--a` is converting the value of `a` to a number and decrement it's value. so like calling `return totalSum(4);`

Then `sum += a` (`sum = "05" + 4` : `sum = "054"`) ...

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation of window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt): *(emphasis mine)*

> result is a **string** containing the text entered by the user, or the value null.